# Python, compare and calculate data in lists

Tags: python, list

I am trying to calculate the attendance in 3 courses.

The raw data in an Excel spreadsheet looks like this (“1” means attended, “0” means no):

[image]

*What’s needed is to calculate:*

In those who attended Course A, how many of them (%) attended Course B, and attended Course C.
In those who attended Course B, how many of them (%) attended Course A, and attended Course C.
In those who attended Course C, how many of them (%) attended Course A, and attended Course B.

The results I have from the codes are here.

*They mean:*

In those attended Course A, 100% attended Course A, 50% attended Course B, and 75% attended Course C.

In those attended Course B, 67% attended Course A, 100% attended Course B, and 100% attended Course C.

In those attended Course C, 75% attended Course A, 75% attended Course B, and 100% attended Course C.

```
Project A to Project A@100%
Project B to Project A@50%
Project C to Project A@75%
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  
Project A to Project B@67%
Project B to Project B@100%
Project C to Project B@100%
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
Project A to Project C@75%
Project B to Project C@75%
Project C to Project C@100%
```

**As you can see, the clumsy codes running isn’t very smart. And if the number of courses (columns) increased largely, for example to 100 columns, manual add-on is a tedious job.**

**What’s the smart way to do such calculations? Thank you.**

```
from xlrd import open_workbook,cellname
import xlwt, xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy 
from xlwt import Workbook,easyxf,Formula

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\\Sheet1.xls")
old_sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

B1 = old_sheet.cell(0, 1).value
C1 = old_sheet.cell(0, 2).value
D1 = old_sheet.cell(0, 3).value

sum_of_Column_B = []
sum_of_Column_C = []
sum_of_Column_D = []

Column_B_B = []
Column_B_C = []
Column_B_D = []

Column_C_B = []
Column_C_C = []
Column_C_D = []

Column_D_B = []
Column_D_C = []
Column_D_D = []


for row_index in range(1, old_sheet.nrows):
#     Column_A = old_sheet.cell(row_index, 0).value
    Column_B = old_sheet.cell(row_index, 1).value
    Column_C = old_sheet.cell(row_index, 2).value
    Column_D = old_sheet.cell(row_index, 3).value

    sum_of_Column_B.append(int(Column_B))
    sum_of_Column_C.append(int(Column_C))
    sum_of_Column_D.append(int(Column_D))

# Paragraph 1
    if Column_B == 1 and Column_B == 1:
        Column_B_B.append(1)    
    if Column_B == 1 and Column_C == 1:
        Column_B_C.append(1)
    if Column_B == 1 and Column_D == 1:
        Column_B_D.append(1)

# Paragraph 2
    if Column_C == 1 and Column_B == 1:
        Column_C_B.append(1)
    if Column_C == 1 and Column_C == 1:
        Column_C_C.append(1)
    if Column_C == 1 and Column_D == 1:
        Column_C_D.append(1)

# Paragraph 3
    if Column_D == 1 and Column_B == 1:
        Column_D_B.append(1)
    if Column_D == 1 and Column_C == 1:
        Column_D_C.append(1)
    if Column_D == 1 and Column_D == 1:
        Column_D_D.append(1)

# Paragraph 1
B_over_B = float(sum(Column_B_B)) / float(sum(sum_of_Column_B))
C_over_B = float(sum(Column_B_C)) / float(sum(sum_of_Column_B))
D_over_B = float(sum(Column_B_D)) / float(sum(sum_of_Column_B))

# Paragraph 2
B_over_C = float(sum(Column_C_B)) / float(sum(sum_of_Column_C))
C_over_C = float(sum(Column_C_C)) / float(sum(sum_of_Column_C))
D_over_C = float(sum(Column_C_D)) / float(sum(sum_of_Column_C))

# Paragraph 3
B_over_D = float(sum(Column_D_B)) / float(sum(sum_of_Column_D))
C_over_D = float(sum(Column_D_C)) / float(sum(sum_of_Column_D))
D_over_D = float(sum(Column_D_D)) / float(sum(sum_of_Column_D))

# Paragraph 1
print B1 + " to " + B1 + " + {0:.0f}%".format(B_over_B * 100)
print C1 + " to " + B1 + " + {0:.0f}%".format(C_over_B * 100)
print D1 + " to " + B1 + " + {0:.0f}%".format(D_over_B * 100)

# Paragraph 2
print " - " * 20
print B1 + " to " + C1 + " + {0:.0f}%".format(B_over_C * 100)
print C1 + " to " + C1 + " + {0:.0f}%".format(C_over_C * 100)
print D1 + " to " + C1 + " + {0:.0f}%".format(D_over_C * 100)

# Paragraph 3
print " - " * 20

print B1 + " to " + D1 + " + {0:.0f}%".format(B_over_D * 100)
print C1 + " to " + D1 + " + {0:.0f}%".format(C_over_D * 100)
print D1 + " to " + D1 + " + {0:.0f}%".format(D_over_D * 100)
```

Comment: Indeed, you need loops.

Comment: Is this a question for Codereview? Because you have a working piece of code, but would like to improve it.

Comment: I can suggest two tweaks: 1) import all the data into a dictionary so you can simply iterate over it instead of writing a line for each variable. 2) use threading to handle the task.

Comment: @Ludisposed, thank you for the comment. actually I am seeking if there're exisiting library, for example Pandas?, can help this type of calculation.

Comment: Yes I do think `panda` may help you in this case. It has some nice functionality with excel, but just loop over the Headers add them to dict and add values to it, to do some calculations [panda.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) might help you in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Dummy data

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np

names = [f'student {i}' for i in range(1, 8)]
courses = [f'course {i}' for i in 'ABC']
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(len(names),len(courses))), index = names, columns=courses)
```

### in reality

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
courses = df.columns
```

You might need to tweak some of the arguments, especially `index_col` and `header`

> df

```
    course A    course B    course C
student 1   0   0   1
student 2   1   1   0
student 3   1   0   0
student 4   0   1   0
student 5   1   0   1
student 6   1   0   1
student 7   1   0   1
```

## Comparison

```
results = pd.DataFrame(columns=courses, index=courses)
for i, j in itertools.product(courses, repeat=2):
    attended = df[df[i] == 1]
    results.loc[i, j] = sum(attended[i] & attended[j]) / len(attended)
```

> results

```
    course A    course B    course C
course A    1   0.2     0.6
course B    0.5     1   0
course C    0.75    0   1
```

So 75% of those that attended course C attended course A

Comment: thank you for the help. a "NameError: name 'courses' is not defined". Could you please have a look?

Comment: you need to define `courses` as `courses = df.columns`

Comment: thank you. but the last line still gives "ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero"...

Comment: so there are courses without people attending them?

Comment: no, no such courses. the raw data's exactly the same as the screen shot. when I "print df", it's different from yours. There's a column on the left to the student names, giving "0 1 2 3 4 5". is this the reason?

Comment: you need to specify that column as index with the argument `index_col=0` to `read_excel()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148865/discussion-between-mark-k-and-maarten-fabre).

Answer (score 2):

my csv looks like this :

```
Name;Course A;Course B;Course C
David;1;0;1
Kate;0;1;1  
Tom;1;1;1
Andrew;1;0;0
Jason;0;0;0
Peter;1;1;1
```

import data like this :

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv',sep=';')
columns = data.columns.tolist ()
columns.remove('Name')
```

Here is a function who takes a Course as input and gives you what you want as output :

```
def assistance(cour):
    print("100 percent of student who assisted {}".format(cour))
    for Course in columns:
        if Course != cour:
            assistance = data.groupby(cour).mean().loc[1, Course] * 100
            print ("assisted {0} at {1} percent".format(Course, assistance))
```

output

```
> assistance('Course A')
100 percent of student who assisted Course A
assisted Course B at 50.0 percent
assisted Course C at 75.0 percent
```

To have all information in a DataFrame :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=columns, columns=columns)
for row in columns:
    for c in columns:
        if row != c:
            df.loc[row,c] = data.groupby(row).mean().loc[1,c] * 100
        else:
            df.loc[row,c] = float(100)
```

output

```
print(df)

         Course A Course B Course C
Course A      100       50       75
Course B  66.6667      100      100
Course C       75       75      100
```

Comment: thank you for the help. an "NameError: global name 'columns' is not defined". Could you please have a look?

Comment: thank you! I tried it also for .xls file, good working! is there a way to output all results into a matrix form, instead of keyin each course to have individual result?

Comment: your efforts are much appreciated. It’s a very difficult decision to choose 1 for the best answer. Hope you don’t mind I choose another as it comes a little earlier. Please do not be discouraged as it doesn’t mean your efforts wasted. In fact, you help and spirit are very precious, making the learning path for lots of people easy. You create a good society.